# Override protected function of block class in Magento 2.1.7

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, override-block

I want to override a protected function `getOptionPrices()` of class `{root_folder}\vendor\magento\module-configurable-product\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable.php`. I have written following code.

**{root_folder}\app\code\Company\Module\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" type="Company\Module\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" />
</config>
```

**{root_folder}\app\code\Company\Module\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Catalog super product configurable part block
 *
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Company\Module\Block\Product\View\Type;

use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ConfigurableAttributeData;
use Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Configurable extends \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayUtils $arrayUtils,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $catalogProduct,
        CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer,
        PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        ConfigurableAttributeData $configurableAttributeData,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $arrayUtils,
            $jsonEncoder,
            $helper,
            $catalogProduct,
            $currentCustomer,
            $priceCurrency,
            $configurableAttributeData,
            $data
        );
    }

    protected function getOptionPrices()
    {
        $customHelper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Company\Module\Helper\CustomHelper');

        $prices = [];
        foreach ($this->getAllowProducts() as $product) {
            $priceInfo = $product->getPriceInfo();
            $stock = $customHelper->getStockData($product->getId());
            $prices[$product->getId()] =
                [
                    'oldPrice' => [
                        'amount' => $this->_registerJsPrice(
                            $priceInfo->getPrice('regular_price')->getAmount()->getValue()
                        ),
                    ],
                    'basePrice' => [
                        'amount' => $this->_registerJsPrice(
                            $priceInfo->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getBaseAmount()
                        ),
                    ],
                    'finalPrice' => [
                        'amount' => $this->_registerJsPrice(
                            $priceInfo->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getValue()
                        ),
                    ],
                    'min_qty' => $stock['minQty'],
                    'max_qty' => $stock['maxQty']
                ];
        }
        return $prices;
    }
}
```

Above code is not working. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding `Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable` instead. This should work.

Comment: Do you mean to replace `class Configurable extends \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable` with `class Configurable extends \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable` ? This did not work.

Comment: did you change class in `di.xml` as well?